# Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted

Tags: ios, shell, ios-simulator, xcrun

I tried to reset the contents and setting of an iOS-Simulator. I find this command line:

```
xcrun simctl erase <deviceID>
```

but i get this error:

```
Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted
```

how is it possible to reset the contents and setting when the simulator is booted?

Thank for helping.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't.  You must shutdown the sim device to erase contents and settings.

Comment: ok, but why it is possible, when i'm doing manually? Simulatar -> Reset Contents and Settings.

Comment: Because that menu item causes the device to shutdown, then erase, then boot again.